# Почему программа переменные приравнивает к нулю?

Tags: c

Необходимо написать программу, которая считывает числа от 1 до 5 с клавиатуры и выводит цитату, которая соответствует данному числу. Если пользователь вводит дробное число - должна быть ошибка, и соответственно, если больше 5 и меньше 1.
Моя программа работает некорректно и не могу понять почему. При вводе любого числа правильного\неправильного, выводится ответ будто при любом раскладе число неверное.
Как будто переменные он приравнял к нулю. 
Помогите пожалуйста понять, что не так.
Спасибо.

```
int main (void){

int x;
double y;

printf ("ml' nob:\n");
scanf("%f", &y);

x = (int)y;

   if ((y - x) == 0 && y>=1 && y<=5){

    if (y==1){
        printf ("Qapla\'\n"
        "noH QapmeH wo\' Qaw\'lu\'chugh yay chavbe\'lu\' \'ej wo\' choqmeH may\' DoHlu\'chugh lujbe\'lu\'.\n");
    }
    else if (y==2){
        printf("Qapla\'\n"
        "Qu\' buSHa\'chugh SuvwI\', batlhHa\' vangchugh, qoj matlhHa\'chugh, pagh ghaH SuvwI\'\'e\'.\n");
    }
    else if (y==3){
        printf("Qapla\'\n"
        "qaStaHvIS wa\' ram loS SaD Hugh SIjlaH qetbogh loD.\n");
    }
    else if (y==4){
        printf("Qapla\'\n"
        "Ha\'DIbaH DaSop \'e\' DaHechbe\'chugh yIHoHQo\'.\n");
    }
    else if (y==5){
        printf("Qapla\'\n"
        "leghlaHchu\'be\'chugh mIn lo\'laHbe\' taj jej.\n");
    }

}
else {
    printf ("luj");
}
}
```

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой никогда нельзя сравнивать подобным образом `(y - x) == 0`, поскольку даже такой код `y = 5` может поместить в y значение 5.00000000000000000001. Это касается всех равенств в вашей программе.

Comment: Объявите `y` как `float`. Учтите и комментарий Alex Krass.

Comment: @Alex Krass: В такой форме это утверждение неверно. Представление плавающих чисел даёт вполне определенные гарантии, которые надо знать и которыми надо уметь пользоваться. Сводить все к тому, что "никаких гарантий нет" не стоит. `y = 5` не может поместить в `y` значение `5.00000000000000000001`.